# How to convert Python Code to Robot Framework

Tags: python, selenium, robotframework

I'm trying to automate the **CAPTCHA** and I have written a python code as well for this. Right now I'm stuck at a point i.e I'm not able to call it in Robot Framework by creating a custom library.

```
from PIL import Image
import string
import json
import os
import time
import pytesseract
import cv2
import numpy as np
import re
from tesserocr import PyTessBaseAPI,PSM, OEM
import time
import logging

captcha_url = "http://www.mca.gov.in/mcafoportal/getCapchaImage.do"
regex = re.compile(r'[\n\r\t ]')#special char plus space

def get_captcha2(session):
    res = session.get(captcha_url, timeout = 10)
    with open("a.jpg", "wb") as f: f.write(res.content)
    img = Image.open("a.jpg")
    captcha = pytesseract.image_to_string(img, config='--psm 8 --oem 0 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
    logging.info("cap: %s"%captcha)
    while not (captcha.islower() and captcha.isalpha() and len(captcha) in  [6,7]):
        time.sleep(.05)
        res = session.get(captcha_url)
        with open("a.jpg", "wb") as f: f.write(res.content)
        img = Image.open("a.jpg")
        captcha = pytesseract.image_to_string(img, config='--psm 8')
        logging.info("cap: %s"%captcha)
    return captcha



def get_captcha(req):
    api = PyTessBaseAPI(psm=PSM.SINGLE_WORD, oem = 0)
    api.SetVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")
    res = req.get(captcha_url, timeout = 10)
    #with open("a.jpg", "wb") as f: f.write(res.content)
    clean_captcha_image(api, res.content)
    captcha = regex.sub("", api.GetUTF8Text())
    conf = api.MeanTextConf()
    cnt = 0
    while (len(captcha) not in  [6,7] or conf<=70) and cnt<=3:
        res = req.get(captcha_url, timeout = 10)
        clean_captcha_image(api, res.content)
        captcha = regex.sub("", api.GetUTF8Text())
        conf = api.MeanTextConf()
        cnt += 1
    return captcha


def break_point(arr):
    for i,n in arr:
        if n:
            break
    return i

def convert_numpy_ipl(trimmed):
    h,w = trimmed.shape
    c = 1
    iplimage = cv.CreateImageHeader((w,h), cv.IPL_DEPTH_8U, c)
    cv.SetData(iplimage, trimmed.tostring(),trimmed.dtype.itemsize * c * (w))
    return iplimage

def clean_captcha_image(api, c_content):
    try:
        arr = np.fromstring(c_content, np.uint8)
        image = cv2.imdecode(arr,0)
        th = cv2.threshold(image,50,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY|cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

        iplimage = Image.fromarray(th)
        api.SetImage(iplimage)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Unexpected error on clean ",e)


def parse_captcha(filename):
    return pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(filename))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import requests
    session = requests.Session()
    session.headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.87 Safari/537.36"}
    get_captcha2(session)
```

I tried to automate the same with Robot Framework but got failed because of session time out. The moment I tried to download the image, the captcha changed.

Comment: Title might be misleading as you are trying to *use* Python code from Robot Framework, not *convert* it, right?

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this example : http://seleniummaster.com/sitecontent/index.php/selenium-robot-framework-menu/selenium-robot-framework-python-menu/228-send-email-in-robot-framework-python-using-gmail

This example should help to convert Python code into Robot Framework keywords.

Answer (score -1):

Follow the below steps to get the function called from within robot file,

Step 1: Create a python file with your function as follows
C:\Users\kgurupra\pyfirst.py

```
def message(msg):
    print ('your message is ' + msg)
    return True
```

Step2: Make sure your .py file in the PYTHONPATH - **THIS IS VERY IMPORTANT STEP**

Step3: Create your robot file as mentioned below,

```
*** Settings ***
Library           String
Library     Collections
Library         Selenium2Library
**Library         pyfirst.py**

*** Test Cases ***
Case1
    message    "hello"
```

Step4: You should see the output as mentioned below,

```
(rf1) C:\Users\kgurupra>robot rbpy.robot
==============================================================================
Rbpy
==============================================================================
Case1                                                                 | PASS |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Rbpy                                                                  | PASS |
1 critical test, 1 passed, 0 failed
1 test total, 1 passed, 0 failed
==============================================================================
Output:  C:\Users\kgurupra\output.xml
Log:     C:\Users\kgurupra\log.html
Report:  C:\Users\kgurupra\report.html
```

[image]

Comment: The py file is not required to be in PYTHONPATH - the framework should be just able to find it. The way you have written it, if it is in the same dir as the .robot file, it will be found - without being in the path. If you specify it as `../mylib.py`, it will look for it in the parent folder. The important step to add it to the PYTHONPATH is just a shortcut - any python program will have access to it, Robot Framework including; but this is actually not very good - you are just polluting your path with random modules and methods.

Comment: Anyways, I don't think your answer addresses OP's ask, he said he created a library. This just repeats the intro in the user guide, the libraries section.